# Gathering the numbers and math

Tags: javascript

So I'm creating a page that asks the user for two numbers and sends them as arguments to four arithmetic functions, addition, multiplication, division, and modulus, and I want the functions to return the values to the calling module.

I'm confused on how I would go about the function, here is what I have so far.

I have addition, but I'm confused as to how I would do this for multiplication, division, and modulus. Basically it gathers the numbers and displays them added, multiplied, divide, and modulus. Here is my code...

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(number1, number2)
{
return number1 + number2;
}

var theFirstNumber = prompt("What is the first number?");
var theSecondNumber = prompt("What is the second number?");

var additionResult = add(theFirstNumber, theSecondNumber);

document.write(additionResult);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The prompt function returns a string, hence when you call your add() function, it just concatenates the values (that's what the operator `+` does for strings). As a quick fix, just convert your variables to number (i.e. using [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)):

```
function add(number1, number2)
{
    return parseFloat(number1) + parseFloat(number2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiply(n1, n2) {
    return n1 * n2;
}

function divide(n1, n2) {
    return n1 / n2;
}

function modulus(n1, n2) {
    return n1 % n2;
}

var theFirstNumber = parseInt(prompt("What is the first number?"));
var theSecondNumber = parseInt(prompt("What is the second number?"));

var multiplyResult = multiply(theFirstNumber, theSecondNumber);
var divideResult = divide(theFirstNumber, theSecondNumber);
var modulusResult = modulus(theFirstNumber, theSecondNumber);

document.write("Multiply Result: " + multiplyResult + "<br/>");
document.write("Divide Result: " + divideResult + "<br/>");
document.write("Modulus Result: " + modulusResult + "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have addition, but I'm confused as to how I would do this for
>   multiplcation, division, and modulus.

You would approach this in the same way as you have for addition:

```
function multiply(number1, number2)
{
    return number1 * number2;
}
function divide(number1, number2)
{
    return number1 / number2;
}
function modulus(number1, number2)
{
    return number1 % number2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your code above is working. Using prompt treats the values as strings so you are concatenating the values together ( 1 + 1 = 11). You need to do as Gerado states and use parseFloat or you can use the Number() function.

As a side note this is perfectly fine for testing but you should also include some error trapping to account for non numeric values. (Look to the IsNumeric() function for this)

```
 function add(number1, number2)
    {
    return number1 + number2;
    }

    var theFirstNumber = prompt("What is the first number?");
    var theSecondNumber = prompt("What is the second number?");

    var additionResult = add(Number(theFirstNumber), Number(theSecondNumber));

    document.write(additionResult);​
```

Comment: var does absolutely nothing to values. It is prompt that returns strings instead of strings.