# Addition, subtraction and multiplication of values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var apples = prompt('Please enter no. of apples');
var oranges = prompt('Please enter no. of oranges');
var fruits = apples + oranges;


document.write(fruits);
```

Why does it work with - and * and not +?

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/17498883 http://stackoverflow.com/q/10414675 http://stackoverflow.com/q/22704963 http://stackoverflow.com/q/12044595 http://stackoverflow.com/q/21215122 and many, many other similar questions

Answer (score 2):

You're adding two strings together to get another string. That's how JavaScript does it.

Maybe what you want is numbers:

```
var fruits = parseInt(apples, 10) + parseInt(oranges, 10);
```

As a note, using `prompt` to collect information is utterly barbaric. What you need to do is have two input boxes and a submit trigger that does the math, or since it's so trivial, hook it up to trigger on any change to either value. jQuery basics here.

Comment: `var fruits = parseInt(apples, 10) + parseInt(oranges, 10);`

Comment: @Oliboy50 A good point!

Comment: Or `parseFloat` to parse floats.

Comment: In this parseInt what does the 10 represent?

Comment: It forces base-10, as `parseInt` will sometimes get ideas and use other bases. For example: `parseInt("0x100")` is 256, but `parseInt("0x100", 10)` is 0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what does parseInt do?
What is radix and base?

Comment: It's just the JavaScript standard [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function. Radix/base is the number system in question. Normal numbers are base-10. Octal is base-8, hexadecimal is base-16.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing string concatenation with the + instead of an addition.
Parse to float or int.

`var fruits = parseFloat(apples) + parseFloat(oranages);`

Answer (score 0):

prompt returns a string, thus it's appending the strings together.
Javascript will convert to an int when you try other operators on the variables.

Use parseInt to make sure they're ints.